# Distance between a point and a line: what's wrong with my calculation?

Tags: vectors

P is the point $(1, 2, 3, 4)$ and Q the point $(4, 3, 2, 1)$. A is the
vector $(1, 1, 1, 1)$. L is the line passing through P and parallel to A.

$$L = (1,2,3,4) + t(1,1,1,1) = (1+t, 2+t, 3+t, 4+t)$$

Given a point X on the line L, the distance between Q and X is

$$QX = (1+t,2+t,3+t,4+t) - (4,3,2,1) = (t-3,t-1,t+1,t+3)$$

The magnitude of this vector is
$$\lVert QX \rVert = \sqrt{(t-3)^2+(t-1)^2+(t+1)^2+(t+3)^2} = 2\sqrt{t^2+5}$$

The minimum distance occurs when $t=0$, and is $2\sqrt{5}$.

At $t=0$,
$$QX = (0-3,0-1,0+1,0+3) = (-3,-1,1,3)$$

When the distance between QX and the line L is at a minimum, the vector QX should be perpendicular to L, i.e. $QX\cdot{L}=0$, but
$$QX\cdot{L} = (-3,-1,1,3)\cdot{(1+t, 2+t, 3+t, 4+t)}$$
$$QX\cdot{L} = -3-3t+-2-t+3+t+12+3t = 10$$

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: the point $P(4,3,2,1)$ is not on the line

Comment: To be perpendicular to $L$ you should check the dot product with $(1,1,1,1)$ which *does* give zero.

Comment: I see, you're right! Thanks!